# How to show a polyhedral is non-empty?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization

A polyhedral is defined as the intersection of finite many closed hyperplane half-spaces.That is,

$P=\{ {\bf a}_i^{\text T}{\bf x} \le b_i, i=1,...,n\}$

I am puzzled about how to show that $P$ must be non-empty? Thanks!

Comment: Such a set may or may not be empty.

Comment: Determining if $P$ is nonempty is often referred to as a *linear feasibility problem*. Many algorithms have been developed for them.

Answer (score 0):

The expression you have used above can also show that the polyhedron is empty like when  A = [1 -1] and b = [1 -1]. Therefore just this expression cannot help to tell you whether the polyhedral is empty or not.

A nonempty set is also a polyhedron and the above expression is for a polyhedron. Therefore you need more information to prove that it's nonempty.